# How do I draw an image and display it with asp:Image, in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, image

I'm making a four-in-a-row-game in ASP.NET.

The game has 6 rows and 7 columns, so I have to be able to build the image with 42 cells with difference colors in it. So do I make 42 small images and then put them all together or what?

And secondly, how do I display that image on a asp.Image control?

Comment: Very low quality question. I suggest you read this: http://tinyurl.com/so-hints

Comment: I'm sorry you feel that way. I don't think it's bad. But I guess i'm gonna delete it then if it's that bad.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use an ASP:Table control and in your codebehind, generate the correct number of columns and rows and as you add them, create an ASP:Image and set the image url and add it to the correct row or column.

It's pretty basic, you should probably google the specific pieces of what you want to do rather than asking people on SO to create the solution for you.

Comment: I think i'll go with a .ashx handler for the image, and the ASP:Table for the cells. The table was a great idea. My idea was to split the image up in cells, but it's better to make many small cells in a table. thanks alot!

Comment: Don't use a .ashx handler for an image, use a `UserControl`.